How to launch a flask application with a domain name on a computer?
I have this simple flask application that I want to deploy. I want to use my own computer as the application's server and I want to give it a domain name. Please give me step by step instructions on how to do that:
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return "hello world"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=50100, debug=True)


I tried to search for solutions on the internet and the flask documentation, but I could not find anything useful.

Not enough information. Do you want the app to be available on your intranet or publicly on the Internet? You may try ngrok for that.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Adding a domain is not specific to Flask, which is why there would be no documentation for it. Broaden your search to DNS Registrars and reverse proxies

Do you have a domain name registered? Does your computer have a public IP address? Do you have access to a public IP address anywhere?

You can't add domain to flask using app.run(host='mydomain.org') because that's not how it works. The host parameter will only accept IP Address / Hostname of your device based on the documentation

So what you need to do you need to run flask on a single IP, and then map it to a domain.
If you're the only one that wants to access Flask using the domain you can map in locally by adding an entry on hosts file on your device which located at:

Windows: C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
Linux: /etc/hosts

If you want everybody to access Flask by using a domain, you need to map it (on the local area network - local DNS server or on a public DNS if your app is available publicly)
